# file upload with django

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I am newbie working with django, I am trying to create a form that permits the user to upload a file. The code I used is pretty much the same as from the djangoproject tutorial but it didn't work. my code is as follows:

for views:

```
from django import forms

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload_file.html', {'form': form})

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open('home/dutzy/Desktop/mysite/name.txt', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

models:

from django.db import models

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file  = forms.FileField()
```

and the template:upload_file.html

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/upload_file/">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b> {{ form.file.label_tag }}</b>  {{ form.file}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" value="title" name="title" id="title" />
                <input type="submit" value="Save" id="Save"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

i am testing my code on the django development server. the error is:**global name 'UploadFileForm' is not defined**, altough i suspect there are also other problems.
i have configured the urls.py as:
`(r'^upload/$', 'mysite.upload.views.upload_file')`

Could someone please take a look at my code and point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: I just asked a very similar question, or at least the solution I think will be the same. Check out @catavarn 's answer here:
[Link to my question/his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614992/problems-with-custom-time-widget)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your form follows these rules http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form

Comment: did this help? i hope it did :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is a simple python error. `UploadFileForm is not defined`

According to what you've pasted, you've only imported stuff from django.

You have to import your `UploadFileForm` from wherever it lives into your view function code, so add `"from myproject.myapp.models import UploadFileForm"`

To reproduce your error:

```
def global_name_error():
    UploadFileForm
global_name_error()
[out] NameError: global name 'UploadFileForm' is not defined
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..I forgot indeed to import the UploadFileForm..now it works in the sense that it displays a form to upload a file, but when I try to push the save button I get a Forbidden (403). CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. I have put the csrf token in the template and I don't understand where the problem is. Could you please help me out with this one too?

Comment: Normally, please ask a separate question, but anyways: I don't see a `{% csrf_token %}` tag in your form code.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Yuji's answer. I would also suggest to define UploadFileForm class in your view instead of the models. It belongs with the presentation logic, not the data/model.